# No module named "panel. pane'; 'panel' is not a package

Tags: python, panel, holoviews, holoviz

Panel and other holoviz package was working fine. But since yesterday, it is not working and gives following error. I checked the site packages, tried creating cond and venv based virtual environments, but dint help me. Has anyone faced similar issue?

Code:

```
from panel.pane import PaneBase
```

Error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "panel.pane"
'panel' is not a package
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

This error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'panel.pane'; 'panel' is not a package
```

may also occur if you have named the main program file you created as `panel.py` and try to run it as `python panel.py` or another file has the name `panel.py` in the same folder from which you run your program. Python will consider your program file as a module and try to find something in it that is naturally not in it. About where Python is looking for modules, see [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path).

In this case, **rename your program file so that its name does not equal with the name of the imported module**.